# In which condition does `preg_split` may return `false`

Tags: php, regex

PHP documentation for `preg_split` states the following:

> Returns an array containing substrings of subject split along boundaries matched by pattern, or FALSE on failure.

I have to write an unit test for this, but I fail to generate any pattern that return false.
In which conditions may that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of failure to perform preg_split due to invalid inputs, preg_split will return false.
Example-

```
$string = array("sdasds"); // Invalid string
$array=preg_split('/[\s,]+/',$string);
var_dump($array); //false

$string = "sdasds";
$array=preg_split('j',$string); // Invalid pattern
var_dump($array); //false
```

In addition to these two parameters it applies for other params also.

```
preg_split ( string $pattern , string $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int $flags = 0 ]] ) : array
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using `print_r` instead of `var_dump` to print my result, that's why I failed to see the returned `false`. Considering my call is protected by typehinted parameters, the only failing case I have to take into account if the invalid pattern.